# How to write query in MySQL for JSON array objects

Tags: java, mysql, sql, postgresql

Based on the requirement I need to change logic.
I have students table and columns like id and val. I want to write a select query.

**Student table** contains data:

**id     val**
1     {"stdId":1,"stdName":"student","stdAddress":"testLoc","stdran":[1,2,3]}

2    {"stdId":2,"stdName":"student2","stdAddress":"testLoc","stdran":[2,3,4]}

3    {"stdId":3,"stdName":"student3","stdAddress":"testLoc","stdran":[1]}

4    {"stdId":4,"stdAddress":"testLoc","stdran":[]}

5    {}

6    {"stdId":5}

I want to show records where if stdran.size()>0 then I need to check whether 1 exists or not. if exits I need to throw that record
and also I need to throw records like where val ={} and val doesn't contains stdran[] and if contains, it's stdran.size()=0

ex: **if input :1**

expecting output

**id     val**  
1 {"stdId":1,"stdName":"student","stdAddress":"testLoc","stdran":[1,2,3]}

3    {"stdId":3,"stdName":"student3","stdAddress":"testLoc","stdran":[1]}

4    {"stdId":4,"stdAddress":"testLoc","stdran":[]}

5    {}

6    {"stdId":5}

if **input :4**

expecting output

**id     val**

2    {"stdId":2,"stdName":"student2","stdAddress":"testLoc","stdran":[2,3,4]}

4    {"stdId":4,"stdAddress":"testLoc","stdran":[]}

5    {}

6    {"stdId":5}

Can anyone help me on this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `JSON_CONTAINS`.. Check [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=8a79d8856b5df19816dc2725ba3eeb72) (mariadb_10.4)

syntax is `JSON_CONTAINS(target, candidate[, path])`

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `student`
WHERE
    JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(`val`, '$.stdran'), '1') 
    OR JSON_EXTRACT(`val`, '$.stdran') IS NULL 
    OR JSON_EXTRACT(`val`, '$.stdran') = '[]'
```

**And result For input 1 is**
[image]

**For input 4  is**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Indra Kumar. I updated my question. if you can help me on this one, please?

Answer (score 1):

I recently came up with the same problem and used these two approaches. See here:
[fetching records from a json object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68038036/16119353)

Comment: if its still not clear you can ask me further in comments. PS: I was dealing with strings and your dealing with int values.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use Json_Contains

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `val` JSON
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1
> VALUES
>   ('1', '{"stdId":1,"stdName":"student","stdAddress":"testLoc","stdran":[1,2,3]}'),
>
>   ('2', '{"stdId":2,"stdName":"student2","stdAddress":"testLoc","stdran":[1,2,3,4]}'),
>   ('3', '{"stdId":3,"stdName":"student3","stdAddress":"testLoc","stdran":[1]}'),
>   ('4', '{"stdId":4,"stdName":"student4","stdAddress":"testLoc","stdran":[2,3]}');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(val,'1', '$.stdran') ;
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> |  2 |
> |  3 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cb95a1af438ad3c9a491cd3eea531e00)*

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `val` LONGTEXT
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1
> VALUES
>   ('1', '{"stdId":1,"stdName":"student","stdAddress":"testLoc","stdran":[1,2,3]}'),
>
>   ('2', '{"stdId":2,"stdName":"student2","stdAddress":"testLoc","stdran":[1,2,3,4]}'),
>   ('3', '{"stdId":3,"stdName":"student3","stdAddress":"testLoc","stdran":[1]}'),
>   ('4', '{"stdId":4,"stdName":"student4","stdAddress":"testLoc","stdran":[2,3]}');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(val,'1', '$.stdran') ;
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> |  2 |
> |  3 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d1d7b8b08edc2ade079cc65cb44b28d)*

Comment: `val` JSON or  `val` longtext which one is right ?

Comment: that doesn't matter MySQL auomnatically converts it, see second example

Comment: I tried both, first example `SELECT * `gives some kind of encrypted values. But longtext is fine. Thats why i asked

Comment: Thanks @nbk . Your query working good. I have a one doubt. How can we retrieve where stdran=[] (empty array). and also want one more query where stdran[] not contains 1. can you help me on this please?

Comment: you know the rules one question only, accept and upvote the answer and ask a new one, but as a hint the NOT JSON_COntaINS  for the latter